# How do I trace React Emotion Styled Components back to their location in the source code

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I have a React application using `create-react-app` with `@emotion/styled` components.

When I look at my code in the browser, I want to be able to see where the code generating the element is coming from. For example, if I can see a `className` for a styled component which includes the filename, this would be a useful clue. Something like:

```
<label class="css-plgvp9-Field.component.js">The code is probably in Field.component.js.</label>
```

For comparison, what I currently get is:

```
<label class="css-plgvp9">Where am I?</label>
```

- Is there a way I can modify the application configuration to do that?
- Is there a better way I haven't thought of to do that?
- Is there any way to do that at all?

The contents of `Field.component.js`:

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

// ...

const Label = styled.label`
  /* ... */
`;
```

It should probably be noted that I'm using `@mui/material` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the way classNames are generated from emotion, you will need to use the babel plugin provided from emotion, reference docs: https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/babel-plugin.

If what you are seeking is a way to override CRA's babel configuration without ejecting, it can be achieved by using these two npm packages, in conjunction:

`customize-cra` and `react-app-rewired`.

See this article for an example usage: https://devinschulz.com/modify-create-react-apps-babel-configuration-without-ejecting/

I believe your resulting `config-overrides.js` file will look something like this:

```
const { override, addBabelPlugin } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  addBabelPlugin(
    [
      '@emotion',
      {
        sourceMap: true,
        autoLabel: 'dev-only',
        labelFormat: '[local]',
        cssPropOptimization: true,
      },
    ],
  ),
);
```